# Identify and remove outliers from a dataframe grouped by subject and condition

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm very new to r and to the tidyverse package, so bear with me.

Basically, I have a within-subject design I collected RTs for. I want to remove all trials that deviate from the participant's mean RT by more than 2.5 SD. I have two conditions Early and Late, so, let's say for each subject, I want to calculate the mean RT for the Early condition and remove the trials where the RT is 2.5 SD above that mean, same for the Late condition.
I would also like to know how many rows were removed.

```
View(data)
Subj Trial     factor   rt 
1     1        Early    324 
1     2        Late     405 
1     3        Early    1093 
1     4        Late     738 
1     5        Early    310
1     6        Early    389 
1     7        Late     1050
1     8        Late     782
1     9        Late     513 
1    10        Early    401
2     1        Early    920 
2     2        Late     627
2     3        Early    520
2     4        Late     629
2     5        Early    302 
2     6        Early    376
2     7        Late     1100
2     8        Late     529
2     9        Late     589
2    10        Early    430 
3     1        Early    366
3     2        Late     499
3     3        Early    1003 
3     4        Late     389
3     5        Early    356
3     6        Early    365
3     7        Late     1234
3     8        Late     345
3     9        Late     300 
3    10        Early    402



data_clean <- data %>% 
  group_by(Subject, factor) %>% 
  filter(!abs(rt - mean(rt)) > 2.5*sd(rt)
         )
```

This seems to work, though I'm not sure if the mean is really taking into account the condition or not.
Also, I don't know what code I can use to know the number of trials that were filtered/removed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct to remove rows, it can also be written as

```
library(dplyr)

data_clean <- df %>% 
               group_by(Subj, factor) %>% 
               filter(abs(rt - mean(rt)) < (sd(rt) * 2.5))
```

To calculate how many rows were removed you can subtract the rows of the original and new dataframe.

```
nrow(df) - nrow(data_clean)
```